# Why jhipster angularjs version returns for authenticate API HTTP 401 instead of HTTP 400 in case of invalid credentials?

Tags: angularjs, jhipster, spring-security-oauth2

based on oauth2 specification https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-5.2  and this question [OAuth 2.0 - Why does the authorization server return 400 instead of 401 when the resource owner credentials are invalid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22586825/oauth-2-0-why-does-the-authorization-server-return-400-instead-of-401-when-the#) jhipster angularjs version should return HTTP 400 Bad Request or not in case of invalid credentials please?

Comment: As far as I know, this is the behavior of Spring Security OAuth2, not something specific to JHipster.